# Call Oracle Stored Procedure from Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Here is my Java code for calling the stored procedure. I keep getting an error saying:
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement

```
public Connection initiateDBConnection() throws NamingException,
        SQLException {

    Connection result = null;
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();

    DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext
            .doLookup(Constants.DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
    result = (Connection) WSJdbcUtil
            .getNativeConnection((WSJdbcConnection) datasource
                    .getConnection());

    return result;
}

public void callStoredProcedure(String procedureName,
        Map<Integer, Object> map) throws SQLException, NamingException {
    OracleCallableStatement statement = (OracleCallableStatement) initiateDBConnection()
            .prepareCall(procedureName);
    Iterator<Entry<Integer, Object>> params = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (params.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, Object> contents = params.next();
        statement.setNString(contents.getKey(),
                (String) contents.getValue());
        System.out.println("Key: " + contents.getKey() + "Value: "
                + contents.getValue());
    }
    statement.execute();
    statement.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the prepareCall method return OracleCallableStatementWrapper object.

```
OracleCallableStatementWrapper statement = (OracleCallableStatementWrapper) initiateDBConnection().prepareCall(procedureName);
```

Also,You could try with [JAVA JDBC API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/callablestatement.html) as follows:

```
CallableStatement statement = (CallableStatement) initiateDBConnection()
            .prepareCall(procedureName);
```

Comment: Apparently, thats what I tried at first but I keep getting SQL92 token not compatible error

Comment: Could be problem with your syntax or JDBC driver does not support that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed in your cose `WSJdbcConnection` which means you are using Websphere. If this is indeed the case, and if you really need to use Oracle specific clasess (`OracleConnection`, etc.) I would suggest that you should look into the `WSCallHelper` class, provided by websphere for 'clean' management of this kind of situation. It provides two main methods, `jdbcCall` and `jdbcPass` for calling methods on and passing native types respectively.

More information is available in this article from IBM: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21409335